# SQL CHECK issue with adding a CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints

This is two-part question involving CHECK statements, In my first CHECK for some reason it works but actually *allows* null to be inserted into the field... any ideas how to remedy this? In my second CHECK, It plain and simple does not work. It's allowing anything to be inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (CONSTRAINT CK_CON (name IN ('Jon','Bill','Ted','Ron','Jeff')));

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (CONSTRAINT CK_NAME CHECK(
         (name='John') OR (name='Mary') OR 
          (name='Jane') OR (name= 'Bruce') OR (name= '')));
```

Comment: Add a NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: In a `WHERE` clause, the entire predicate has to be `TRUE` in order to match. In a `CHECK` constraint, the predicate needs to not be `FALSE`. Where this makes a difference is precisely in the areas of `NULL`s and the fact that SQL has a three-valued logic which sometimes produces `UNKNOWN` when `NULL` crops up.

Answer (score 3):

as for first question change column `name` to `not null`

as for second question

try do it such way

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (CONSTRAINT CK_NAME CHECK(
         (name='John') OR (name='Mary') OR 
          (name='Jane') OR (name= 'Bruce') )); -- you have to remove this OR (name= '')
```

Comment: I'm getting the error - USER.CK_NAME - check constraint violated. No ideaaa why?

Comment: because you have value name inserted related to the checking you provide. you have to clean your data or modify you checking depending on what you want

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (CONSTRAINT CK_CON (name IN ('Jon','Bill','Ted','Ron','Jeff')));

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD (CONSTRAINT CK_NAME CHECK(
         (name='John') OR (name='Mary') OR 
          (name='Jane') OR (name= 'Bruce')));

Can prove this

Comment: I think so but prove this

Comment: When u create a table and put constraints i think so but i dont sure. If not u can prove make a function for restrinctions